# Oracle 12c RAC GV$SESSION EVENT column

Tags: oracle, session

I have an oracle 12c rac cluster with 2 nodes.

If i execute this select statement:

```
select  * from gv$session where osuser = sys_context('USERENV','OS_USER');
```

i will get 3 rows:

- 1 Session with column EVENT = 'PX Deq: Execute Reply'
- 2 Sessions with column EVENT = 'PX Deq: Execution Msg'

Is it a valid assumption, that, in this case the session with EVENT = 'PX Deq: Execute Reply' is **always** the query coordiantor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about what you've provided above, but if you want to find the query coordinator for all parallel query operations, you can query v$px_session (or gv$px_session). The QCSID column is the coordinator.